# Capacitor 3 / Ionic 6.18.1 Error: "PushNotifications.register()" is not implemented on android

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I'm trying to get the "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.8" to work.

Everything seems fine and all the solutions i have found looking around are not working for me.

I have tried:

- Editing MainActivity.java
- Changing Gradle files.

But no luck with the things i found.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this. ( also trying this on an emulator and https server )
I did read that it would not work on https but not sure why.

Comment: use pushNotifications with https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm

Comment: I am using the same capacitor plugin without any issues.
Did you already add the google-service.json file to your android platform?

Answer (score -1):

Do this when your app is starting

```
import {
    PushNotifications,
    Token,
    ActionPerformed,
    PushNotificationSchema
} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';

...

async initPush(): Promise<void> {
        if (this.platform.is('hybrid')) {
            await this.registerPush();
        }
}

 private async registerPush() {
     const permission = await PushNotifications.requestPermissions();
        if (permission.receive === 'granted') {
            // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
            await PushNotifications.register();
        } else {
            // No permission for push granted
            console.log("error");
        }
}
```

Also if you are using Capacitor 3, your MainActivity.java should look like this:

```
package com.your.package.name;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

}
```